# How to use date DatePipe with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ionic3, ngx-translate

I have this translation defined:

"...has created **{{param1}} ({{param2}})** on {{ param3 | date:'mediumDate' }}, {{ param3| date:'shortTime' }}"

param1 and param2 get replaced but param3 is not ({{ param3 | date:'mediumDate' }}, {{ param3| date:'shortTime' }} is printed)...how can I use the datepipe inside a translation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you define your translation like that, ngx-translate expects 
{{param3 | date:'mediumDate' }} as is.

Instead just try following

```
"...has created {{param1}} ({{param2}}) on {{ param3 }}, {{ param4}}"
```

When you want to get your message, use it as follows

```
{{'path.to.your.message' | translate: {param3: yourDateVariable| date: 'mediumDate'}}}
```